# Evaluating algebra expression using an auxiliary VB class compiled on the fly and consumed in a C# project

Tags: c#, parsing, vb.net, reflection, math-expression-eval

- I want to create algebra evaluator but I don't want to write my own parser because it takes much time to learn.
- I don't like algebra expression in C# because it does not look natural compared to VB counterpart. For example, "x^2+1" in VB must be written as "Math.Pow(x,2)+1" in C#.
- I am still a newbie in the world of programming and always interested to learn the best practices. I am always not confident with my code.

### Minimal Working Example

Based on the 3  constraint given above, I tried to implement it as follows.

**First**, I create a template named `template.vb` as follows:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Math
Namespace AnyNamespace
    Public Class AnyClass
        Public Function AnyMethod(ByVal x As Double) As Double
            Return expression-in-x
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

where `expression-in-x` is just a place holder that will be replaced. See the next code how I replace it.

**Second**, I create a class named `Parser.cs` as follows:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;


namespace Mathematics
{
    public static class Parser
    {
        static string expression;
        static object obj;
        static MethodInfo mi;

        public static string Expression
        {
            get
            {
                return expression;
            }
            set
            {
                expression = value;

                string source;

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("template.vb"))
                {
                    source = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("expression-in-x", expression);
                }

                CompilerParameters cps = new CompilerParameters();
                cps.GenerateExecutable = false;
                cps.GenerateInMemory = true;

                CompilerResults crs = (new VBCodeProvider()).CompileAssemblyFromSource(cps, source);

                if (crs.Errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (CompilerError ce in crs.Errors)
                    {
                        sb.Append(string.Format("Error Number : {0}, Line : {1}, Message : {2}.\n", ce.ErrorNumber, ce.Line, ce.ErrorText));
                    }
                    throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Assembly a = crs.CompiledAssembly;
                    obj = a.CreateInstance("AnyNamespace.AnyClass");
                    mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("AnyMethod");
                }
            }
        }



        public static double Evaluate(double x)
        {
            if (expression == null)
                throw new Exception("Unitialized expression.");
            try
            {
                return (double)mi.Invoke(obj, new object[] { x });
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException error)
            {
                throw error;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                throw error;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Last**, I test the code as follows:

```
using Mathematics;
using System;

namespace Tester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parser.Expression = "x^2+1";
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(Parser.Evaluate(x));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

### Questions

Is what I did above recommended? If not, could you give me a direction or suggestion what should I improve it or whatever to make it much better?

Comment: This comment will be deleted shortly: Hi guys, I will visit this question tomorrow as it is time to sleep. Good night. Zzzz...

Answer (score 4):

```
public static class Parser
```

Why is this class static? When you have a class with some state, you should almost never make that state static. For example, you might be very surprised when you try using this code from multiple threads.

---

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("template.vb"))
{
    source = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("expression-in-x", expression);
}
```

You could have used [`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368) to make this simpler.

---

```
CompilerParameters cps = new CompilerParameters();
cps.GenerateExecutable = false;
cps.GenerateInMemory = true;
```

Using `var` and object initializer, you can shorten this to:

```
var cps = new CompilerParameters { GenerateExecutable = false, GenerateInMemory = true };
```

Also, `cps` is not a great name, don't shorten names unnecessarily.

---

```
obj = a.CreateInstance("AnyNamespace.AnyClass");
mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("AnyMethod");
```

Instead of object and `MethodInfo`, you could store the method as a delegate:

```
Func<double, double> compiledFunction;

…

var obj = a.CreateInstance("AnyNamespace.AnyClass");
var mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("AnyMethod");
compiledFunction =
    (Func<double, double>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<double, double>), obj, mi);

…

return compiledFunction(x);
```

As another advantage, this is likely going to be faster, since it's not using reflection for every invocation of `Evaluate()`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is what I did above recommended?

Parts of it yes, other parts no.

Using the `using` keyword is good.
Using a `StringBuilder` to append/concat Strings is good.

> but I don't want to write my own parser

But you name your class Parser, which is misleading.

> ```
>     public static double Evaluate(double x)
>     {
>         if (expression == null)
>             throw new Exception("Unitialized expression.");
>         try
>         {
>             return (double)mi.Invoke(obj, new object[] { x });
>         }
>         catch (TargetInvocationException error)
>         {
>             throw error;
>         }
>         catch (Exception error)
>         {
>             throw error;
>         }
>     }
> ```

First you are catching the exception and then you are throwing it. If you can't handle the exception, you shouldn't catch it. Also using your style `throw error` will discard all the useful information of the stacktrace. In the case you really need to rethrow an exception, but you need to add some information, you should create a new exception and pass the catched exception as the inner exception to the constructor like

```
try
{
    return (double)mi.Invoke(obj, new object[] { x });
}
catch (TargetInvocationException error)
{
    throw new TargetInvocationException("Evaluate has thrown an exception because blabla...", error);
}
```

Brackets should be used also for "oneline" expressions of `loops` and `if` so

> ```
> for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
>       Console.WriteLine(Parser.Evaluate(x));
> ```

should be

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Parser.Evaluate(x));
}
```

Your `Expression` setter is doing to much. You should refactor the loading and compiling of your assembly to a method. For the loading you should also refactor the `Errormessage composition` to a separate method.

Last but not least, I want to suggest that you should create a real expression parser. You will learn a lot by this experience.